# PHP Image gallery with lazyload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to build an image gallery with php and lazyload. I have around 8000 images which shouldn't load at once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <?php
                $dir = "img/";
                $i = 0;
                if (is_dir($dir)) {
                    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                        if(is_file($dir . $file)){
                             echo "<img class='lazyload' data-src='img/$file' src='img/$file' width='auto' height='600px'>";
                        }
                      }
                    closedir($dh);
                    }
                } ?>

<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can load every pic at once in the img folder but I am not able to load more while scrolling down. I don't want to load all images at once.

Comment: You can try the new lazy loading attribute if you want https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr https://addyosmani.com/blog/lazy-loading/ I haven't tried it yet, but it sounds awesome.

Comment: How about getting each image individually with Ajax/JavaScript? 8000 Images are a lot to render to the DOM, you should also think about unloading them when they are no longer visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can just remove the `src='img/$file'` and it will work fine.
The issue might be due to a wrong images src path, here is a static images working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
   
<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>

<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>

<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>

<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>

<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>

<img class="lazyload" data-src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
<img class='lazyload' data-src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80' width='auto' height='600px'><br><br>
                
</div>
```

Comment: For me it wont work. If I remove src='img/$file' it shows me a blank page.

Comment: Please review my updated answer, it might be a starting point for you.